# Delete a comment in a swarm review

Tags: swarm

On the swarm review page, I only see an option to archive comments. Is there a way to delete a comment that has already been posted (with or without a delay notification flag)?

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, you can't delete a comment

Comment: Okay, agreed. But the answer could be more detailed including references where this is declared and written. Otherwise it looks as if the answer was plucked out of thin air...